# Delphi - convert content to binary data - equivalent to pack() in PHP

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE2, is there a command in Delphi equivalent to pack() in PHP?  I need to convert a Delphi record containing integers and strings into to binary, for transmitting over TCP.

Comment: If you really just have a string, you don't need `pack`; you can just sent the string as-is. You'd only need `pack` if you had lots of values to send in a single unit. There's no built-in function for that, but it wouldn't be hard to write. (But `unpack` could be tricky, if you need that, too.)

Comment: Thanks, sorry should have been more clear - it is a set of mixed data values I need to send in a single unit.

Comment: @JonathanWareham: Is it a record? If so, does it contain variable-length or fixed-length string types? You should give the precise details, because they matter.

Comment: Hi Andreas, it is a record and consists of integers, a fixed length string and a variable length string.

Comment: Actually `pack()` returns a string.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=delphi+serialization&sourceid=opera&client=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest  
http://code.google.com/p/superobject/wiki/first_steps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750072
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=serialize+delphi&submit=search

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method that will convert a generic record into binary form (or vice versa). You will need to either:

1. Write your own dedicated code to do so, or
2. Find and use an object persistence library.