# Is there a generic library to hold Delphi application's user defined values

Tags: delphi, generics, user-defined

After I added too many user defined values to my application, I had to develop something like below. And now, it is getting complex. I do not want to keep developing this tool. At least, I would like to compare my tool's properties to other solutions.

So, I wonder if there is a generic solution for this kind of job. I googled but I do not know right keywords for this approach (I use Delphi 6. I can read C++ and C#).

My goal is,

- Avoid coding user defined parameter definition
- Avoid coding user defined parameter user interface and coding business rule
- In code, accessing parameter as if strictly defined (not like this: `GetParameter('parameter_name_str')`)
- In code, accessing parameter without type casting from a generic type

--

Okay, I wrote a tool program. By using it, one can produce xml files like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <parameters>
      <parameter id="PrinterEnable">
        <description>Select yes to use printer.</description>
        <group>Printer Settings</group>
        <title>Enable Your Printer</title>
        <type>boolean</type>
      </parameter>
      <parameter id="PrinterConnection">
        <description>You can refer to your printer's manuel to select correct cable.</description>
        <group>Printer Settings</group>
        <title>How to connect your printer</title>
        <type>list</type>
        <items>
          <item value="1">Usb</item>
          <item value="2">Serial</item>
          <item value="3">Parallel</item>
        </items>
      </parameter>
      <parameter id="PrinterWidth">
        <description>Enter width of paper to use in millimeters</description>
        <group>Printer Settings</group>
        <title>Paper Width</title>
        <type>integer</type>
        <default>25</default>
        <min>20</min>
        <max>200</max>
      </parameter>
    </parameters>
```

Then, same tool, automatically creates two files: A Delphi rc file includes a referance to above xml file and (after ask me a few question like class name, unit name) another Delphi pas unit file like this below :

```
    unit AppParameters;

    interface

    uses
      libParameters3;

    type
      TAppParameters =class(TParameters3)
      private
        FFileName :string;
      public
        constructor Create;
        procedure Load;
        procedure Save;
            function PrinterEnable: Boolean;
        function PrinterConnection: Integer;
        function PrinterWidth: Integer;
      end;

    implementation

    uses
      Classes, Forms, SysUtils, Windows;

    { AppParameters }

    constructor TAppParameters.Create;
    var
      AStream :TResourceStream;
    begin
      AStream :=TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'APP_PARAMETERS', RT_RCDATA);
      try
        inherited LoadDefFromStream(AStream);
      finally
        AStream.Free;
      end;

      FFileName :=ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.ini');
    end;

    procedure TAppParameters.Load;
    var
      AFileStream :TFileStream;
    begin
      AFileStream :=TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
      try
        LoadValFromStream(AFileStream);
      finally
        AFileStream.Free;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TAppParameters.Save;
    var
      AFileStream :TFileStream;
    begin
      AFileStream :=TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite);
      try
        SaveValToStream(AFileStream);
      finally
        AFileStream.Free;
      end;
    end;

    function TAppParameters.PrinterEnable: Boolean;
    begin
      Result :=GetParameter('PrinterEnable').AsBoolean;
    end;

    function TAppParameters.PrinterConnection: Integer;
    begin
      Result :=GetParameter('PrinterConnection').AsInteger;
    end;

    function TAppParameters.PrinterWidth: Integer;
    begin
      Result :=GetParameter('PrinterWidth').AsInteger;
    end;

    end.
```

After all, in Delphi on my real code, I can use it like this below:

```
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      AWidth :integer;
    begin
      FAppParameters :=TAppParameters.Create; //defined in TForm1 private

      FAppParameters.Load;
      if FAppParameters.PrinterEnable then begin
        case FAppParameters.PrinterConnection of
          1 : begin end; {Do Usb}
          2 : begin end; {Do Serial}
          3 : begin end; {Do Parallel}
        end;

        AWidth :=FAppParameters.PrinterWidth;
        //Do something with AWidth
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Form2 :=TForm2.Create(Self);
      try
        Form2.Caption :='Options';
        FAppParameters.PopulateEditor(Form2, Form2);
        Form2.ShowModal;
      finally
        Form2.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: You could easily serialize any class to json or xml using RTTI if you had a more modern version of Delphi.

Comment: So should I search it as "serialization" ?

Comment: Yes, but D6 is limited in its reflection capacities. Some help in this Q [How to save an object to a file in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3750072/576719).

Answer (score 0):

As you don't mention XML as a constraint and use Delphi 6, I'd like to propose to use the Windows registry instead with standard TRegistry class. The Windows registry is the hierarchical database to store application settings.

```
uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Registry, Forms;

procedure SaveFormLayout(const AForm: TForm);
var
  R: TRegistry;
begin
  R := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    R.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER; // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE requires admin rights
    R.OpenKey('My Software\Forms\' + AForm.Name, true);
    R.WriteInteger('Top', AForm.Top);
    R.WriteInteger('Left', AForm.Left);
    R.WriteInteger('Height', AForm.Height);
    R.WriteInteger('Width', AForm.Width);
    R.WriteInteger('WindowState', integer(AForm.WindowState));
    R.CloseKey;
  finally
    R.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Registry settings can be easily exported into the file and then imported with REGEDIT or REG command line Windows utilities so you can migrate user profile like a file copy.

Comment: I cold not explain what I am searching for or I discovered something new.

In your example, 

* You should code twice every string of first parameters (ie 'Top'). One for WriteInteger, one for ReadInteger.
* You should also create user interface of that parameter so user can edit the values.
* You should also code some control logic ie what if user entered string for 'Top' parameter rather than an integer number.

In my program, there are over 50 parameters since I started developing. I do not want to add manually another 90 parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I should first thank you for your interest and example you gave.